# PyQt adding QLayout error

Tags: python, layout, pyqt

I am attempting to display an array to the screen in through PyQt. I have created the object that I want to display and array and it is called `tableView` in Qt Designer. It is a QTableView.

When I try to run this code;

```
tablemodel = MyTableModel(my_array, self)
tableview = QTableView()
tableview.setModel(tablemodel)

layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
layout.addWidget(tableview)
self.setLayout(layout)
```

I get the following error;

```
QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to MyWindow "MainWindow", which already has a layout
QWidget::setLayout: Attempting to set QLayout "" on MyWindow "MainWindow", which already has a layout
```

Any help on this issue to display `my_array` would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What is the type of `self`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `QMainWindow` class is different to most other widgets in that it has a built-in layout, which it uses for laying out the menubar, toolbars, statusbar and dock-widgets:

[image: QMainWindow Layout]

As you can see, it also leaves space for a central-widget, which is where you need to put your own content. So your code needs to look like this:

```
tablemodel = MyTableModel(my_array, self)
tableview = QTableView()
tableview.setModel(tablemodel)

widget = QWidget()
layout = QVBoxLayout(widget)
layout.addWidget(tableview)
self.setCentralWidget(widget)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
layout = QVBoxLayout()
layout.addWidget(tableview)

layout2 = QVBoxLayout(self)
layout2.addLayout(layout)
```

Comment: This removes the second line of the error but still have the first. Also still no output to the screen.

Comment: you have to add tableview.show() to make it visible in the layout